# making huge pixel images fit to the given width and height

Tags: html, css, image

I got a problem with images and its pixels probem.well let me tell you this.I got a picture of 2448 x 3264 pixels. So its a big image I just decided to reduce its size using this way

```
 <img src="1.jpg" style="width:600px;height:500px"/>
```

But there is a  problem I see, the picture looses its clarity and its visibility, it looks like pulled it close and the person in the images looks so ugly.but using the original size makes look so big . I am sure there is a way to do because I see google images result and also on some websites I tried to see thier code but Could not figure it out.

Could anyone please tell me how do i make the images look good even when they got too long resolution and make them fit in the given width?

**Update**

Okay now i understand we need some server side image processing and could anyone tell me what would be the way to do it Thanks

Comment: [For anyone that may come accross this question] If you are HTML5-ing it you can have a look at 'canvas' and 'drawImage()' http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most wide-used practice is to resize the image server-side. When the image is uploaded to the server  (e.g. by the user) the server takes it and creates and creates needed thumbnails.

Unfortunately this cannot be done with HTML, CSS nor JavaScript. And there are a lot of cons of forcing the size of the image with CSS. For example the user have to download the whole image ( I guess yous is about 6MB ) and it could take a lot of time .

Answer (score 0):

Withour any language you cant do it, or you have to edit the image and need to upload to your host.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the plain html. It will also help if you have the right width:height ratio (in this case, 3:4)

so:

```
<img src="1.jpg" width="375" height="500"/>
```

Comment: I cannot see how is this better than the CSS and how can you maintain the same aspect ratio since you're forcing both width and height ?

Comment: This will not maintain aspect ratio as you're forcing width and height- incorrect solution.

Answer (score 0):

To gain better quality you need something more, then only HTML. You have to resize images manually, either use some server-side scripting to prepare images before rendering (better even do it on uploading if you sure about specific dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is server side image processing. For exaple [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) or another implementation depending on your serwer platform.

Example:

```
<img src="../phpThumb.php?src=1.jpg&w=600" />
```

the phpThumb will open image passed in **src**, and resize it to width passed in **w** -> the process image on the fly and outputs to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

For pictures to maintain their clarity, you need to ensure that you maintain aspect ratio. Aspect ratio is the width/height ratio of images and if you resize images maintaining the ratio, then their clarity is maintained. You are getting the resized image to be messed up because 2448/3264 != 600/500.

Now  tag resizes by aspect ratio, if you give only one of the attributes of width or height. eg:

```
<img src="your_src" width=600>
```

This will render maintaining aspect ratio(it calculates the height needed). However, this could lead to problem sometimes if you have a max-height constraint, because the recalculated height could exceed the div height, if your div has a max-height.

If you have a max-height and max-width constraint, you can use the following code to resize the image using JS. I am assuming that max-width and max-height values as 600px and 500px respectively and you can change as per your needs:

```
height = this.clientHeight;
width = this.clientWidth;

aspectRatio =  width / height;
if (height > width)
{
    height = 500;
    width = height * aspectRatio;
}
else if (width > height)
{
    width = 600;
    height = width / aspectRatio;
}
this.setAttribute("height", height+"px");
this.setAttribute("width", width+"px");
```